# Display multiple cell values in a single cell in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, join, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I made a small algorithm that helps me organize how I study with the Pomodoro studying technique, it displays the amount of hours I'll spend on a single subject, how much I'll spend a day on all the given subjects, in a week, and a month. I want to have all the values displayed in separate cells, and in one cell, like this: N Minutes per subject (N Hours), N Minutes Daily (N Hours), N Minutes Weekly (N Hours), N Minutes a month (N Hours). When I add the equations to the H15, it returns "FALSE" for some reason?

I am really, really new to Google Sheets, I have a bit of programming experience, and my programming experience is telling me that I should store the equations that I have in C2-G4 in a variable, and almost *print* them to the place where I want everything centralized.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vLEMi8G9MmIz3K-hXNkfQu5oJDINeVkoo6tA5WPIqfs/edit?usp=sharing I hope I'm not doing something wrong :D

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: @player0 damn I really am new, I updated it, I hope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=C2&" Minutes per subject ("&TRUNC(C4, 2)&"), "&CHAR(10)&
 D2&" Minutes Daily ("&TRUNC(D4, 2)&" Hours), "&CHAR(10)&
 E2&" Minutes Weekly ("&TRUNC(E4, 2)&" Hours), "&CHAR(10)&
 F2&" Minutes a month ("&TRUNC(F4, 2)&" Hours)"
```